# Phonegap 5.3.6 audio not playing on kitkat, but playing on lollipop

Tags: cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I use Phonegap 5.3.6.

I got a simple working phonegap scripts to play MP3 files. 
It runs well on my Nexus 4 (Lolipop 5.1.1), the sound is playing well. No problem at all.

But when I tried on Asus Zenfone 5 (KitKat 4.4.2) and Chinese Tablet (Kitkat 4.4.1) the script works, but the sound is mute. Not playing at all.

How to make Asus Zenfone 5 and Chinese Tablet playing the sound?

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <title>Test Audio</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="app">
      <p>Sidhi Ciang</p>
      <p>
        <h1 id="h01"></h1>
        <a data-role="button" id="playClip"> -= PLAY =- </a>
      </p>
    </div>  

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sound.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my sound.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    var mySounds=[new Audio("sound/click0.mp3"), new Audio("sound/click1.mp3"),  new Audio("sound/test.mp3")];

    $("[id^='playClip']").click(function(e) {
        var arrayIndex = 1;
        alert("OK");
        mySounds[arrayIndex].play();        
    });
});

function sidhi() {
    alert("asafd");
}
```

Already installed plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-media 1.0.1 "Media"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

Comment: did you able to find alternative to Crosswalk?  I don't want to much to install 3x time extra size of my current project, just only because of sound

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem working with my gameapp.....the problem is that lollipop and kitkat have some differences in their webviews......consider using CROSSWALK project in your app.....but this increases your app size by about 18mb......Its easy to use. You just need to install a plugin in your current project and then build your project as usual.

Comment: i experienced the same problem for my game-app and i searched a lot regarding this but i ended up using crosswalk